# LWUIT Table's cells formatting

Tags: lwuit, defaulttablemodel

I have  a LWUIT Table that contains a DefaultTableModel which itself contains some values written on 
it cells.

I just want to change my table's cells formatting. In other words   I want to set the  direction of  values in cells from Right to Left  instead of Left to Right direction.

```
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

import  com.sun.lwuit.*;

import com.sun.lwuit.table.*; 

public class Format_Table_Cells extends MIDlet
{

Form f;

Table  table1;

DefaultTableModel model1;

public void startApp() 

{
com.sun.lwuit.Display.init(this);

f = new Form();

Object obj5 [][]= { { " "," ","row1"}  , { " "," ","row2"} , { " "," ","row3"}  };

model1 = new DefaultTableModel( new String[]  { "column1" , "column2"   ,"column3" } ,obj5); 

for(int j=0;j<obj5.length;j++)

for(int col=0;col<obj5.length;col++)

try 

{  

model1.setValueAt(j, col, obj5[j++][col++] )   ; 
} 

catch(java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ee)
{
}
catch(java.lang.NullPointerException e3)
{
}

table1 =new Table(model1,true);

f.addComponent(table1);

f.show();

}

public void pauseApp() 
{

}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional)
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem , just by made an space left the quotation sign

```
Object obj5 [][]= {             { " "," ","    row1"}  , { " "," ","    row2"}   ,  { " "," ","    row3"}    };
```